# Stored Procedure security when user in more than one group (SQL Server 2016)

Tags: sql-server

I have two AD groups: GROUP A and GROUP B

GROUP A contains User1, User2, User3
GROUP B contains User1

I have 3 stored procedures
SP1 GROUP A Grant Execute

SP2 GROUP A Grant Execute

SP3 GROUP A Deny Execute, GROUP B Grant Execute

SP3 doesn't run for User 1, guessing as the Deny from Group A overrides Group B Grant, is this true?

How can I make this work without removing User1 from GROUP A and adding GROUP B to all SP's... or not possible.

Comment: `DENY`>`GRANT`. That's always how permissions have worked. Personally, I find that it's best to have `DENY` permissions in their own role. Mix and Matching `GRANT` and `DENY` tends to result in problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it is currently setup, it is not possible as the 'DENY' will always take precedence over the 'GRANT'.

You would need to create another security group called GROUP C and remove User 1 from other groups and add them to this one. You would then apply GRANT to SP1 and SP3 for Group C.